# How to load HTML's in between header and footer

Tags: angularjs

I have many html's each having their separate state & controller and are loaded based upon state called. I have header and footer which are included in all the HTML's with ng-include tag. Is there any better way other than this to make header & footer as contants and load pages in between them rather than including them in all the pages using ng-include.

Comment: What for? Once they've loaded once, if they come from the same files in every page, they should be saved in the user's computer so you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: Yes you are correct but the purpose is why unnecessarily load all these pages rather than loading only the HTML that is needed

Comment: if youre using angular, why arent you using routing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-include for example:

```
<div ng-include="'header.php'" class="navbar-fixed-top"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
<div ng-include="'footer.php'" class="navbar-fixed-top"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Index.html only place ur .js,.css files and add    in body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    //css files
</head>
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="">
   <ui-view></ui-view>
//script files
</body>
</html>
```

Now seperate ur navbar and footer in seperate nav.html and footer.html and also maintain one js file and add

```
angular.module('app')
        .component('app', {
            template:
            '<navigation></navigation>'+
                '<ui-view></ui-view>' +
            '<footer></footer>' 
        });
```

where navigation is navigation component name

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .component('navigation', {
            templateUrl: 'app/common/nav/nav.html',
            controller: NavController
        });
```

similarly footer is footer component name.In the same way u can do for all controllers

```
 angular
        .module('app')
        .component('home', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: homeController
        });
```

By this navbar and footer will be common for all pages and only ui-view changes.